# How to merge/join two file based on common field with repeated rows

Tags: awk, join, merge

I have 2 file:

`file1`

```
SC  65.696  618
SC  61.92   625
KN  82.546  1037
KN  82.946  1032
KN  82.849  1032
CN  70.55   618
```

and

`file2`

```
SC  SC7  SCARE      588     2       75702
KN  KN4  Kines     1033     2   1   3635
CN  CNGC Prote      703     2       3880
```

need to join, according to column 1 and with repeated rows

`file3`

```
SC  65.696  618     SC  SC7     SCARE   588     2       75702
SC  61.92   625     SC  SC8     SCARE   588     2       75703
KN  82.546  1037    KN  KN4     Kines   1033    2   1   3635
KN  82.946  1032    KN  KN5     Kines   1033    2   1   3636
KN  82.849  1032    KN  KN6     Kines   1033    2   1   3637
CN  70.55   618     CN  CNGC    Prote   703     2       3880
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Hi again, the problem is sixth column of file two, which some rows were empty. so after joining, this column were merged by seventh column,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of `join`:

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
CN 70.55 618 CNGC Prote 703 2 3880
KN 82.546 1037 KN4 Kines 1033 2 1 3635
KN 82.849 1032 KN4 Kines 1033 2 1 3635
KN 82.946 1032 KN4 Kines 1033 2 1 3635
SC 61.92 625 SC7 SCARE 588 2 75702
SC 65.696 618 SC7 SCARE 588 2 75702
```

Comment: Note that for `join` to work properly, the input data files needs to be sorted on the join field (the 1st column in this case).

Comment: thanks, updated

Comment: It happened to work without sorting this time, probably because the files had the same ordering. But in the general case...

Comment: Oh, thank you all and sorry, I had searched before and not find anything useful. anyway, I should look better. thanks again

Comment: To join on a field other than the first, use `-j